# How to rewrite querystring url

Tags: asp.net

Need help,

Assuming I have a site: `http://mysite/test.aspx`

and I passed a querystring like this: `http://mysite/test.aspx?id=1234`

How can I change the url in the address bar like this: `http://mysite/1234` 
and how can I get the value of `1234`? can I still use `Request.QueryString["id"]`?

I'm using C# asp.net.

Many thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Just use Request.QueryString["id"] and if you want to change your url from `http://mysite/test.aspx?id=1234` to `http://mysite/1234` do the following:

If you're using ASP .NET 4 then do something like this:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("",
    "mysite/1234",
    "~/mysite/test.aspx?id=1234");
```

If you're using ASP .NET 3.5 or lower try to do this:

```
Browser.Url = new System.Uri("http://mysite/1234", System.UriKind.Absolute);
```

Comment: where shall i write this line? browser.url

Comment: routes.MapPageRoute("",
    "mysite/1234",
    "~/mysite/test.aspx?id=1234"); where to put this line? and how would you call it? can you post a sample code? many thanks sir

Answer (score 0):

What you need is called URL Rewriting. There are multiple ways to do it depending on complexity of your application and URLs.

I worked on URL re-writing few years ago. We had a complicated system with even more complicated query string values.

I used [**Helicons ISAPI**](http://www.helicontech.com/) engine for rewriting. Avialable in both both paid and free version. Please look into it if your application demands it. You will need to write lots and lots and lots of RegEx though. But, overall amazing tool.

If you requirements are simple (i.e. to rewite a few pages), you can use free libraries such as **[urlrewriter](http://urlrewriter.net/)** which might help you and make your life easier if you want to rewrite for multiple pages in one shot.

At last, very simple and easy way to rewrite URLs: read this tutorial from **Scott Gu** and you will understand what you need to do:

**http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx**

If you want those pretty URLs to be generated on it's own when you click on the hyperlink with your query-string value, you will definitely have to work at IIS level (which URL re-writing libraries will do for you).

I could have posted some sample code to do it but I thought the above tools and tutorial from **Scott Gu** will help you understand what you need to do and in a much better way.